# ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager - How to read user-mgt.xml file

Tags: ldap, wso2

in the user-mgt.xml file, I have a UserStoreManager with a list of properties. How can I "read" the properties from inside my project? Because I would like to write the configurations of my Ldap only once, in the user-mgt.xml file instead of writing them also inside the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the user store configuration property using,

```
realmConfig.getUserStoreProperty('<property_name>');
```

Comment: also do I always need to open a new connection to Ldap like this LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null); or is it possibile to have an open session once the server is started?

Comment: realmConfig will be available from the parent class. So you can access it. And about the new connection, yes you can open a session once the server started.